# vb.net how to update an existing database/datasoure/dataset

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, bindingsource, tableadapter

I have got a SQL Database that is connected to a vb2012 application. I have updated the database and I want to update this within Visual Studio.

Everytime, that I have tried to do this previously; I have had to delete the dataset, data source and data connection and re add it.

I have got a table adapter and binding source within the application so I basically need to update the whole package.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know if this suits you but, have you tried to update your database directly in Visual Studio, update its edmx file and deploy the database? That would update the database from VS to SQL Server. I guess you would still have to delete the dataset and re-add it but you would gain a step less in the process

Comment: I did try that once but it didn't really work. I have copied the database and log from the original location into the project folder and overwritten the existing ones. This has then prompted everything else to update itself. I just need to find out whether this has broken my table adapter.

Comment: You tried it by copying the DB and log to the project folder?

Comment: Yeah that's what I have just done and it worked.

Comment: Check your table adapter and, if everything is fine, post an answer to your own question, it may help others

Comment: No table adapter is ruined. I cannot even open the page to view. It is because the tables and things have been renamed. Do you know how I can fix this. As I had to delete 4 pages last time and completely re-do them?

Comment: Hmm, not sure but probably you'll have to do it the hard way. What I meant in the first comment was to have your DB written in VS, in `*.sql` files. That way, you don't need to use SQL server anymore, changing everything in VS and deploying the DB after. That way, tables, triggers, SP's, etc. are all updated automatically. I believe datasets aren't updated automatically though.

Comment: Yeah Im guessing so lol. Ohh right, I don't know how to do that. But hopefully this is the last time I will be updating my database. As I can add the data in VS if I need to. It was only because I have just restructured my whole database so hopefully I wont have to do it again. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @chiapa I have managed to fix it. I had loads of errors but I just went through each one and changed the old name to the new one and I think its worked :)

Comment: Great man, glad you got it!